# Error in for loop while trying to plot a surface

Tags: r, r-plotly

I'm trying to plot a 3d surface in R but it looks like something is wrong in the for loops when both my X's and Y's values are positive.

It's is a very simple function and for loop but I don't see a mistake yet, still the final surface is different from what it was supposed to be (a normal plane in this case). Any thoughts of what may I be missing?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)    

x = seq(-5,5)
y = seq(-5,5)
fxy = matrix(0,length(y),length(x))
dim(fxy)

result = function(x,y){
  x+y
  }

for (j in y) {
  for (i in x) {
    fxy[i,j] = result(x[i],y[j])
  }
}

fig = plot_ly(z = ~fxy, x = x, y=y)
fig = fig %>% add_surface()

fig
```

[image: Text]

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should use `seq_along(x)` and `seq_along(y)` instead of `x` and `y`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)    

x = seq(-5,5)
y = seq(-5,5)
fxy = matrix(0,length(y),length(x))
dim(fxy)

result = function(x,y){
    x+y
}

for (j in seq_along(y)) {
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        fxy[i,j] = result(x[i],y[j])
    }
}

fig = plot_ly(z = ~fxy, x = x, y=y)
fig = fig %>% add_surface()

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer user12728748. I think I was passing the whole vector to the function instead of each element by itself. seq_along() solved the issue!

Comment: Not exactly; you tried to address a negative index where x and/or y were negative, in your `fxy[i,j] = result(x[i],y[j]` line. Try this toy example: `fxy = matrix(seq(1, (length(y)*length(x))),length(y),length(x)); fxy[1,1]; fxy[-1,1]` to see what happens then...